# How to create curved background in android layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I had done some changes in height and width of map layout and got the output as below
[click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8Lkw.png)
but i want the .XML file to look like this 
[click to view image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKCuy.png)
this is what i want to get. which i had done in paint to show you

any help on how to get this output will be great help for me

code of map.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/red"
tools:context="p.httpwww.intosanket.login">
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="300dp"
tools:context="p.httpwww.intosanket.MapsActivity" />
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/msg"/>
<EditText
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="  E-Mail/Adresse"
    android:id="@+id/e1" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/lock"/>
<EditText
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="  Password"
    android:id="@+id/e2"/>

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sign In"
    android:id="@+id/b1"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Register"
    android:id="@+id/b2"/>
```

Comment: can you paste your layout here

Comment: yaa sure i will

Comment: Its incomplete..  Please post complete layout(didn't close with LinearLyout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a bit of my time..

There may be many other smart ways to do it. But the following solution came into my mind..

The trick is draw image in paint convert it to svg then to vector. Set that image as src for image view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FF0000"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="p.httpwww.intosanket.login">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        tools:context="p.httpwww.intosanket.MapsActivity" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/bg" />

</RelativeLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/msg" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/e1"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="  E-Mail/Adresse" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/lock" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/e2"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="  Password"
        android:paddingTop="12dp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign In" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Register" />

</LinearLayout>
```

the src for the imageview bg.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="300.000000dp"
android:height="137.000000dp"
android:viewportWidth="300.000000"
android:viewportHeight="137.000000">

<group
        android:translateY="137.000000"
        android:scaleX="0.100000"
        android:scaleY="-0.100000">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#ff0000"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:pathData="M2985 1328 c-38 -250 -110 -449 -230 -634 -221 -340 -558 -571 -965 -660 -68 -15 -127 -19 -295 -19 -168 0 -227 4 -295 19 -620 136 -1073 603 -1184 1221 -13 73 -14 25 -15 -587 l-1 -668 1500 0 1500 0 0 685 c0 377 -2 685 -4 685 -2 0 -7 -19 -11 -42z" />
</group>
```

[image: Final result is]

Comment: Thank you sir. It help me a lot and save my lot of further time.

Comment: It goes without saying sir. you have given solution to my problem

Comment: sir do you have any idea that how can we break a line and start it from next line in toast. as /n or <br> does not work. hope you got what i want to say.