# How to make imageView cross over out of layout?

Tags: java, android

Haii.... i need help to design my `imageView` from this screen shoot [image: curent layout] to be like this [image] i need the `imageView` crossed from layout, i am using some of library in this activity like [SlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)  and imageview from [CircleImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) if i want to search in google what the keyword or anyone can give me any solution?

here is my layout.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        sothree:umanoPanelHeight="100dp"
        sothree:umanoParallaxOffset="100dp"
        sothree:umanoShadowHeight="20dp"
        sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/dragView"
        tools:context="com.idiots_international.jajan.activities.nearby.NearbyActivity"
        sothree:umanoOverlay="true">
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:id="@+id/map"
                  tools:context="com.idiots_international.jajan.activities.nearby.MapsActivity"
                  android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
    </LinearLayout>

        <!--map/top view-->
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/nearbyRelLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <!---->
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:orientation="vertical">

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                            android:layout_width="96dp"
                            android:layout_height="96dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/jajan_logo_3"
                            app:civ_border_width="2dp"
                            app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>

                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/ShowAddressTextView"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Click on Marker to view Address "
                            android:textColor="#000"
                            android:textSize="15dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="11dp"/>

                    <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
                        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
                    </ScrollView>
                </LinearLayout>
                <include layout="@layout/layout_bottom_navigation"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

Working but need to remove the outline in here :
[image: working fine need to remove outline]

Comment: This comment is not an answer but it is very similar
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49344573/how-to-create-curved-background-in-android-layout/49346092#49346092

Comment: what is android:pathData= ? it contain number but i canot understand

Comment: It is easy, i'll post an xml sample soon.

Comment: i am waiting @Khemraj

Comment: Hey dude, i got busy, just posting it. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<!--map/top view-->
<RelativeLayout 
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/nearbyRelLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <!---->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ShowAddressTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Click on Marker to view Address "
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="11dp"/>

            <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/jajan_logo_3"
            app:civ_border_width="2dp"
            app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it's working but still need a little bit effort to remove outline in RelativeLayout, i've tried `android:background="@null"
            android:id="@+id/nearbyRelLayout1"
            android:stateListAnimator="@null"
            android:outlineProvider="none"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:padding="@null"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"` and the outline still up there,but i think it's because i am using [SlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) have you try it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">



            <LinearLayout
                android:background="#643122"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

       <!--Your Top view (the map) goes here-->

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

       <!--Your Bottom view (the text) goes here-->

            </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/bg"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```

**OUTPUT IMAGE**

[image]

Comment: i got an error android:adjustViewBounds="true" not supported

Comment: Remove it and continue working. It was meant for a simple imageView.

Comment: yess i did, i remove it and no error but my image was gone

Comment: Please check the new answer with output image. I found some inconsistencies in the previous answer I gave.

Comment: thanks for answer it working but only need a little bit effort to remove outline in the frameLayout, but i think it's because i am using [SlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) have you try it?

Comment: Which outline are you talking about?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168468/discussion-between-syam-houng-and-abhi).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use white background for the parent of Circle image view, this will not let see background map.

You can implement this with following layout idea. Feel free to ask if you cant reach requirement

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        // margin top half of circle image view height
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        >
    </LinearLayout>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks all for advices, the outline appear from child of my SlidingUpPanel and i am done with set `sothree:umanoShadowHeight="-10dp"` cheers!

Comment: Cool ;) syam houng